# Why is java copying instead of creating a new Instant When i use different variables?

Tags: java

I made a fairly simple code and i got into an error which confused me.

So I have a class that creates two totally different variables and creating them using the new keyword

```
Player playerLeft = new Player(5,150);
Player playerRight = new Player( 150,150);
```

Player class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Player extends JComponent {

    private int posY;
    private int posX;

    public Player(int x, int y) {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
        //repaint();
    }

    public float getMovementY() {
        return movementY;
    }

    public void setMovementY(int movementY) {
        this.movementY = movementY;
    }

    int movementY = 0;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D _g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(posX, posY, 20, 150);
        _g2.fill(rect);
    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
        posY = y;
        posX = x;
        repaint();
    }

    public void move() {
        setLocation(posX, posY + movementY);
    }
}
```

It's probably me not knowing something about Java but for me when I try to instantiate playerRight it just overwrites player left and drawsOut playerRight only.

Here is the complete code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class mainJFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    int relativeTimeMillsec = 0;

    Player playerLeft = new Player(5, 150);
    Player playerRight = new Player(150, 150);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            relativeTimeMillsec++;
            refreshTimeText(relativeTimeMillsec);
            calcMovements();
        }
    };

    //components
    JLabel timeCounterLabel = new JLabel("Time: " + 0, SwingConstants.CENTER);

    public mainJFrame() {
        createComponents();

        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void createComponents() {
        this.setTitle("The title");
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10);

        JButton testButton = new JButton("Label");
        testButton.setSize(100, 25);
        testButton.setLocation(this.getWidth() / 2 - testButton.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2 - testButton.getHeight() / 2);

        timeCounterLabel.setSize(200, 25);
        timeCounterLabel.setLocation(this.getWidth() / 2 - timeCounterLabel.getWidth() / 2, 10);

        //playerRight = new Player(this.getWidth()-45,this.getHeight()/2);

        // this.add(testButton);
        this.add(timeCounterLabel);
        this.add(playerLeft);
        this.add(playerRight);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        {
            super.repaint();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            playerLeft.movementY = +2;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            playerLeft.movementY = -2;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            playerRight.movementY = +2;
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            playerRight.movementY = -2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    private double calcRealRelativeTime(int _relTime) {
        return relativeTimeMillsec / (double) 100;

    }

    private void refreshTimeText(int _relTime) {
        timeCounterLabel.setText("Time: " + Math.round(calcRealRelativeTime(_relTime)));
    }

    private void calcMovements() {
        playerLeft.move();
        playerRight.move();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Understand that a JFrame's contentPane (the container that holds its components) uses BorderLayout by default, and this code:

```
    this.add(timeCounterLabel);
    this.add(playerLeft);
    this.add(playerRight);
```

is adding all components to the same default BorderLayout.CENTER position, meaning any components added will replace components added previously.

But more importantly, yours is a common problem and stems from your having your Player class extend from a GUI component. Don't do this, as then you will have a great deal of difficulty drawing multiple Player objects and having them interact easily (as you're finding out). Instead have Player be a logical (non-component) class, and have only *one* class extend JPanel and do all the drawing. This class can hold Player objects, perhaps held in a collection such as an `ArrayList<Player>`, and then iterate through the collection within its paintComponent method.

Other issues:

- Do not use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` for Swing animations since these classes do not follow Swing threading rules. Use instead a `javax.swing.Timer`.
- Learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others
- If/when you do override a painting method such as `paintComponent`, be sure to call the super's method within your override, usually on the first line, so as not to break the painting chain. Also, use the `@Override` annotation before this method and any other methods that you *think* that you may be overriding so that the compiler catches possible errors with this.

For example (but not a complete example)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleAnimation extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
    private Player2 playerLeft = new Player2(5, 150, Color.RED);
    private Player2 playerRight = new Player2(150, 150, Color.BLUE);

    public SimpleAnimation() {
        playerLeft.setySpeed(1);
        playerRight.setySpeed(-1);
        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        playerLeft.draw(g);
        playerRight.draw(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerRight.move();
            playerLeft.move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleAnimation mainPanel = new SimpleAnimation();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleAnimation");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
class Player2 {
    private static final int RECT_WIDTH = 20;
    private static final int RECT_HEIGHT = 50;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int ySpeed;
    private Color color;

    public Player2(int x, int y, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setySpeed(int ySpeed) {
        this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
    }

    public int getySpeed() {
        return ySpeed;
    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

    public void move() {
        setLocation(x, y + ySpeed);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```